# javascript will not make web requests

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I am using an html document in my firefox web browser and is a file on my machine and Ive tried looking at web requests but it is showing none. I know for sure I have internet here is a reproduceable code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>StackOverFlow</h1>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" language="javascript">

$.getJSON('https://jsonip.com/', function(data) {
  document.writeln("<p> " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + "</p>");
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two `<script>` tags - one for `jQuery` and one for your code:

```js
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Your code here
</script>
```